# Error de instalación del lenguaje de programación Latino en Arch Linux

Tags: linux, latino

Al momento de escribir make y make install da como resultado:

make: make: *** No se especificó ningún objetivo y no se encontró ningún makefile.  Alto.

make install: make: *** No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo 'install'.  Alto.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! SIn saber mas.. poco podemos hacer...

Answer (score 0):

Recientemente termine de crear un script que permite la instalación de Latino y todas sus librerías y dependencias para Linux (Solo Linux, no mac)

Aquí te lo comparto, solo tienes que abrir tu terminal, copiar y pegar este script y el script hara todo por ti, solo te pedirá por el admin password.

```
git clone https://github.com/lenguaje-latino/instalacion.git && cd instalacion && sudo chmod +x latino_instalacion-linux.sh && ./latino_instalacion-linux.sh
```

Si quieres aprender mas sobre la instalación de Latino en ArchLinux/Manjaro, mira la documentación aquí:

https://manual.lenguajelatino.org/es/stable/OS/ArchLinux-Manjaro.html